# "Don't use any strength with your foot", is the sentence correct and clear?

Tags: meaning

Suppose I am teaching my son to juggle a football(soccer). Similar situation like [Should I use present continuous or present simple tense here to describe an action in a video?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/249484/115654)

> Raise your foot. Hold the ball, and then drop it freely down to your foot. **Don't use any strength with your foot**, consider your foot the ground, just let the ball touch your foot and bounce up by itself the same way it bounces on the ground.

By "don't use any strength with your foot", I mean don't kick actively, is the sentence correct and clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't sound idiomatic to me. When talking about physical motions, I think it's much more common to say "don't use force" than "don't use strength". And it's still more common to say "keep your foot relaxed" than "don't use force with your foot".

So it would make sense to say:

> Raise your foot. Hold the ball, and then just drop it onto your foot. Keep your foot relaxed, think of your foot as the ground, just let the ball bounce off your foot the same way it bounces off the ground.

(I made a couple of other changes, too, but my other changes aren't very important.)

You might also want to say "keep your foot still" instead of "keep your foot relaxed". If you keep your foot *still* as the ball bounces off of it, you're using muscular effort (or force, or strength) to keep your foot from moving. If you keep your foot *relaxed* as the ball bounces off of it, you're allowing your foot to move due to the force of the ball.